# Do unobserved/non-awaited tasks impact ASP.Net website performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, garbage-collection, task

If I have the following code called in an ASP.Net application will there be an impact on the performance having tasks that are not awaited? Do unobserved tasks cause issues upon garbage collection, and are there issues if the task if faulted but the exception was never accessed?

```
    public async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(string customerId)
    {
        Customer customer;

        // Call the two tasks
        var customerTask = GetCustomerAsync(customerId);
        var alcoholicBeveragesTask = GetAlcoholicBeveragesAsync();

        customer = await customerTask;

        if (customer.Age >= 21)
        {
            // Only await the task if we have to since it may be long running
            var alcoholicBeverages = await alcoholicBeveragesTask;
            customer.AddBeverages(alcoholicBeverages);
        }

        return customer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that you will execute `GetAlcoholicBeveragesAsync()` no matter what. That task will run to completion regardless of whether you await it or not. Awaiting does not run a task, it waits for it. Likely, this is not desirable. The performance impact is running this task. Awaiting usually is not a performance concern in web applications since the frequency of awaits is low.

There are no inherent GC issues. When the task is done all memory is thrown away.

Unobserved task exceptions no longer crash the process by default. I consider it bad practice to drop (and not log) errors since this might hide bugs. So ideally you would still log all errors. You can do that inside that task, or attach a continuation to log errors or wrap it in another helper method that logs exceptions.